# how to access a key after to_json in ruby

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

I have an except message I want to parse as an JSON object in order to read out a key value pair in it. Message looks like

```
{"message":"my message","error_code":404}
```

code looks like this:

```
rescue Exception => e
   puts e
   error = e.to_json
   error_json = JSON.parse(error)
   error_code = JSON.parse(error_json)['error_code']
end
```

seems odd to me that I have to parse this twice. Shouldn't `error` already be a JSON object? If I try to print out the value with error['error_code'] I just says 'error_code'

How can I access the value in the `error` variable?

Comment: you can pass it to hash instead of JSON right?

Comment: after this line `error_json = JSON.parse(error)` the result is a Hash. passing it to `JSON.parse` again wont work cause its not json anymore. You can do `error_json['error_code']`

Comment: why do i need `to_json` and `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: `to_json` convert the `Exception` which is a ruby object into a `json string` and then JSON.parse convert that `string` into a hash.

Comment: Who is raising the error ? It might be useful to create your own error class that has a `error_code` method. Because if you need to `to_json` and parse it to have your error code, it means the code is already inside the `Exception` error.
Then, you'll rescue your own error class and not `Exception` anymore.

Comment: @brcebn is absolutely right here - there is nothing OK about this code. You should not be rescuing Exception and there is no good reason why JSON should be involved here at all. What is this? Present the actual problem that this code is supposed to solve. https://thoughtbot.com/blog/rescue-standarderror-not-exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @brcebn and @max I realized I was trying to solve the wrong problem here.

I wrote a customized exception and now I have no problem:

my_exception.rb

```
class MyError < StandardError
  attr_reader :message
  attr_reader :error_code
  def initialize(msg, error_code)
    @msg = msg
    @error_code = error_code
    super(msg)
  end
end
```

calling the exception in my_service.rb

```
...
raise MyError.new("my message", response.code)
```

finally in my file:

```
rescue Exception => e
   error_code = e.error_code
end
```